# getting TypeError: .finalize is not a function in Rxjs6

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

In the following function, I am getting a runtime error `TypeError: this.authService.authServiceSigninUser(...).map(...).catch(...).finalize is not a function`.

Question 1) Why Typescript is not catching this error at compile time? How could I catch this error at compile time.

Question 2) How could I resolve the error? I tried using both `finally` and `finalize` but both are not working.

```
public signinUser(user:UserSigninInfo):any{

    this.loaderService.show(); //this shows a spinner
    return this.authService.authServiceSigninUser(user)
      .map(response=>{
        console.log('response from backend service',response);
        let result= <HttpResponse<any>>response; 
        let authToken = result.headers.get("x-auth-token")
        if(authToken == null) {
          console.log("no authToken")
        } else {
          console.log("authToken is ",authToken)
          localStorage.setItem('id_token', authToken);
        }
        return result;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError)
    .finally(()=> this.loaderService.hide()) //hide the spinner
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import this line in your component

**import {finalize,catchError,tap} from 'rxjs/operators';**

**Try this Code**

```
 public signinUser(user:UserSigninInfo):any{

    this.loaderService.show(); //this shows a spinner
    return this.authService.authServiceSigninUser(user)
      .pipe(tap(response=>{
        console.log('response from backend service',response);
        let result= <HttpResponse<any>>response; 
        let authToken = result.headers.get("x-auth-token")
        if(authToken == null) {
          console.log("no authToken")
        } else {
          console.log("authToken is ",authToken)
          localStorage.setItem('id_token', authToken);
        }
        return result;
      })
      ,catchError(this.handleError)
    ,finalize (()=> this.loaderService.hide())); //hide the spinner
  }
```

Comment: thanks. Will try that. Will `finally` also work BTW?

Comment: If u want to use finally means use rxjs-compact package in your package.json file

Comment: I have got `"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0"` in package.json so shouldn't my original code work?

Comment: Your code worked. I'll appreciate if you could let me know why my logic didn't work even though I have `rxjs-compact` in `package.json`

Comment: @ManuChadha rxjs-compact package supports for Angular5 packages not for angular6 packages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172043/discussion-between-vignesh-and-manu-chadha).